# An SQL query to find orphaned image attachments and their meta

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is for people who are good with MySQL queries. I'm using phpMyAdmin locally to try to optimize an old WordPress & Woocommerce site which has gone through a couple of iterations over the years.

I should have **~2000** orphaned image attachments in the `wp_posts` table and each should have a couple of related entries in the `wp_postmeta` table. I'm trying to clear them out completely.

I've figure out how to locate these image attachments:

- they share this in common with ~160 live products: `wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND wp_posts.post_parent = 0 AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID`
- but they *do not* possess a `meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'` row in `wp_postmeta`, only the live products do.

I just don't know how to combine those two statements into an SQL query to find these old products which do not have the `_thumbnail_id` row. I've tried some combinations of `NOT EXISTS` to no avail, but I don't know if I'm using it correctly or if I need to use another method.

My approach (maybe you have a better one?) is to locate and delete those products from `wp_posts` based on these two conditions, and then delete their orphaned metadata from `wp_postmeta` (which should be easy enough for me).

Comment: Read up on MySQL `LEFT JOIN`. You need to join data from 2 separate tables.

Comment: Whenever I find myself thinking how to do things like that with complex SQL, I remind myself that you can write a simple php script and use WP_Query & all the other stuff. Unless you really, really want a pure SQL-version, it's much cleaner to use the WP delete functions (and it's easier, too).

Comment: @WebElaine I've been implementing LEFT JOINs to some extent in other places as I try to optimize this old database, but I haven't been able to figure it out for my above example... i try to use it with NOT EXISTS to compare the post ID across tables but the method only returns a boolean and then either executes the rest of the query or not, which is not really what i intended.

Comment: thanks @janh, I may have to look into it if no one provides an answer here. been trying to do it all from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You might need to run multiple queries. Save the IDs from the first 'share this in common' - then run a second query where ID is in your array of IDs AND your 'do not possess' meta query.

Comment: A similar question here has various SQL suggestions: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/364025/sql-how-to-find-all-attachments-that-are-not-used-in-any-posts-pages-custom-pos