# SQL: How to find all attachments that are not used in any posts/pages/custom_post_types

Tags: images, mysql, attachments, sql, optimization

I have a wordpress installation where the posts also contain attachments that were not embedded in the content by using the `media library -> add`.

I would like to find all attachments that are not used in any posts/pages/custom_post_types

It is ok for me if I get results for attachments uploaded for a specific month, for example **january 2017**.

Here is my attempt to write the SQL:

```
select distinct a.*
from (
    select *
    from wp_posts
    where post_type = 'attachment'
    and post_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
) as a,
(
    select post_content
    from wp_posts
    where post_type in ('post', 'page', 'custom_post_type_1', 'custom_post_type_2', 'custom_post_type_n')
    and post_status = 'publish'
) as p
where p.post_content not like CONCAT('%/wp-content/uploads/', DATE_FORMAT(a.post_date, '%Y/%m'), '/', a.post_name, '%')
```

Since not all attachments were embedded in the content via the media library, I cannot use:

```
select *
from wp_posts
where post_type = 'attachment'
and post_parent = 0;
```

Does anyone know a better way? My SQL query is quite slow.

Comment: Have you considered doing this via WP CLI? Doing this via WP CLI or in PHP with `WP_Query` is trivial. Just keep in mind not every `attachment` is "attached". If I set my sites header image, that header image won't have a post parent, and would incorrectly show as _unused_ in your query. The same goes for attachments that appear in multiple posts. If the original is deleted, it'll show as unattached despite being used multiple times. Attachments that are uploaded on the post edit screen but never used won't show in this either giving false negatives

Comment: How would you do it with WP_CLI? You are right about the false negatives, that is why I am using this statement in the SQL: where p.post_content not like CONCAT('%/wp-content/uploads/', DATE_FORMAT(a.post_date, '%Y/%m'), '/', a.post_name, '%')

Comment: That won't catch things like featured images etc which are stored as post IDs. As for WP CLI, the standard post subcommand takes all the same parameters `WP_Query` does, e.g. `--post_type="attachment"`. If I might ask, why are you querying for unused attachments?

Comment: Ah you are right. I have a Wordpress installation where the editors have uploaded 47.000 images over time while having 3000 posts/pages/custom post types and now they asked me to give them a list of all attachments that are not used anywhere anymore so that they can decide which ones to keep and which ones to delete. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You'll have to caveat whatever answer you give them by saying there is no 100% foolproof way to do this. There will always be a chance they delete something that's in use. it's also possible they've asked you this because they have their own X Y problem, where they've concealed problem X, and devised a solution, e.g. the site is slow, if we delete attachments we'll speed up the site, lets ask our dev which ones aren't in use. In which case it won't speed up their site

Comment: They want to have a manageable media library now. Until now they never bothered searching for an existing image and re-using it - they would just give it whatever filename and upload it again. I told them that while disk space is huge, it' not infinite and they should consider be more rational about uploading images. Also they have uploaded many screenshots that are only need for a week or so, but they never bothered deleting them when replacing them with new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seek isn't truly possible. You can get sort of close, but you cannot definitively say if an attachment is or isn't in use.

We can get somewhere close to a solution, but to do this we will need to process each attachment individually.

So first, get a list of all the IDs of attachments. Use a standard `WP_Query` to do this, you might even get a speed boost from object cache as a result.

Here's the official date query docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

For each attachment:

- Check all post content and post meta for the attachments URL, with the image size removed
- Check all options and post meta for the attachments ID
- Check if the attachment has a post parent
- If any of these are true, the attachment is probably in use

Doing every attachment in a single go will be problematic, it won't be possible to run the query from a browser due to the PHP execution limit. You'd need to do attachments in batches, or via a CLI command. Preferably in batches of 100. PHP will run out of memory if you try to process all 47k at once.

However, the most effective means of testing if an attachment is in use, is to spider the entire site and save the results locally, then search the folder for the URL. Note that this won't catch things that only show once forms submit, or RSS specific stuff, things that only show to logged in users, etc

Comment: I thought of spidering the website too, so luckily I got the crawl log with all the image urls. What I will do is process all attachments in batches (by 100 or per month) by fetching individual ones and trying to match their URL in the crawl log. It will not be fast, but definitely more accurate.

Comment: If you separate each check you can do them all in parallel, there's lots of room for speed improvement here, otherwise run it in the background over night

Answer (score 3):

I found a useful SQL query [here](https://neliosoftware.com/blog/how-to-remove-unused-images-from-your-media-library-in-wordpress/) which addresses many of the points Tom mentions. I've tweaked it a bit for my purposes.

```php
$ids = $wpdb->get_col(
    "SELECT i.ID FROM $wpdb->posts i
        WHERE i.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND i.post_parent > 0
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts p WHERE p.ID = i.post_parent)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND pm.meta_value = i.ID)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_product_image_gallery' AND pm.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%', i.ID,'%'))
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts p WHERE p.post_type <> 'attachment' AND p.post_content LIKE CONCAT('%', i.guid,'%'))
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm WHERE pm.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%', i.guid,'%'))"
);
```

This should find all attachments

- With `post_parent` greater than 0.
- Whose `post_parent` refers to a non-existent post.
- Which isn't used as the featured image (`_thumbnail_id`) for any post.
- Which isn't used in any WooCommerce product gallery.
- Whose `guid` (which usually means the attachment's URL) doesn't appear in any post content.
- Whose URL doesn't appear in any postmeta value.

Once you have the list of IDs you can loop through it and call `wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_id, true )` to force delete each attachment and its accompanying postmeta, as well as the associated media file.

The query for product gallery IDs is a bit crude, though it's good enough for me, and the post content search won't work for you if the URLs of your attachments are different from their `guid`s.